Improving intelligibility of 4-bit speech with ffmpeg
I have mono 4-bit narrowband PCM audio representing speech. It was apparently created by naively truncating 8-bit PCM without dither (although the source was already noisy).
There is a lot of quantization noise in the audio and a little clipping too. Are there any filters I can use with ffmpeg to improve its intelligibility? Mean RMS volume is -2.6dB. This is what I have right now:
-af highpass=100,lowpass=4000,anlmdn=2,speechnorm

which highpasses at 100Hz and lowpasses at 4kHz, uses a non-local means denoiser, then normalizes the speech. This is MUCH better than nothing but I wonder if there is more I can do?
